# Using tab buttons to change fragment without using viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am currently using TabLayout + ViewPager to swipe and change frangments in the viewpager, on tab item click or swipe. But since I am having a timed calendar view in the fragments which requires its own horizontal and vertical scroll - I need to be able to disable swiping only for changing fragments while it still works within each individual fragment... fragment should change only on button click

I dont have any code to paste here as all the research points to either disabling swipe using viewpager2 or using custom code for ViewPager - in both cases I can no longer swipe.... where do I go from here?

Comment: best would be to use [navigation components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) with tab layout

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ViewPager2, you can use:

```kotlin
viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

Otherwise, you can create your own custom ViewPager which ignores all the touch events.

```kotlin
class NoScrollViewPager @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ViewPager(context, attrs) 

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Here we return false to signal that the touch event has not been handled here.

Comment: Hi Arpit, will this disable touch events for the views as well or only towards changing the fragment? I still need horizontal and vertical touch for the content in the fragment...